# Two OnClick events overlap, causing the first one to stop executing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick, toggle

I am trying to fit a new jQuery toggle function within an already working code. Basically, the toggle function should show/hide the below lying div `form_fields_con` with an onclick event.

The problem is that the `form_fields_con` div contains AJAX functionality triggered as well with an onclick event.

Toggle works when nothing in the `form_fields_con` div is changing but once clicked, the toggle function stops working.

This is the toggle function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide_search").show();

    $('.show_hide_toggle').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = this,
        sliding = $(this).closest('div').next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(function() {
            $($(self).children()[0]).text(function(_, txt) {
                return txt == "–" ? "+" : "–";
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the AJAX one contained in `form_fields_con` div:

```
function selectcombobox(fuelcombobox, fuelid, fuelContainer, field_name) {
    var popupvar = jQuery.noConflict();

    popupvar('#'+fuelcombobox).css('display', 'none');
    popupvar('#'+fuelid).css('display', 'block');
    popupvar('#'+fuelContainer).css('display', 'none');
}
```

HTML and CSS posted in a JSFiddle here, to avoid too long post:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bradg/v8hzLt7f/1/

NOTE: For some reason I cannot simulate the error in JSFiddle, apologies for that.

How to prevent the two onclick functions' collision?

Answer (score 0):

You change/recreate the DOM elements holding the onClick listener, a simple approach to get around your problem is event-delegation: http://api.jquery.com/on/ (see se second argument)

```
$('.slidingDiv').on('click', '.select_con_car', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5m2mwd9h/

Comment: Isn't this controlling the onClick for the toggle function? The problem actually happens when the onClick event is triggered for the underlying dropbox - then the onClick for the toggle function stops executing.

Comment: Perhaps i missunderstood you. To prevent a an event theres preventDefault() and stopPropagation()

Comment: I tired to apply different versions of stopPropagation() on the inner onClick event but none of them seems to do the job...that's why I need help :(

Comment: Sorry i cant get you, more confusing is that you cant create a fiddle for it